# Multiple WHERE Query to eliminate data?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need help creating a large query to select a subset of data.

I need to filter out certain information before I can do my analysis. First I select any call which reached my programs. Then I need to filter out all of the fake/test calls. Then I need to eliminate the ineligible calls which is dependent on a few factors like if the Owner or Sender column is a specific designation, or if the Creator column is a specific designation ONLY IF the call type is one of two options. It is super complicated for me.. hopefully someone can help.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Table1
    WHERE SiteID
    IN ('Site1', 'Site2'))
WHERE CustomerID <> (108 different values)
   AND OwnerID <> (A)
   AND SenderID <> (A)
   AND CreatorID <> (A) but ONLY if CallType <> CallType1 or CallType2;
```

Comment: How does your table structure look like ? What kind of values does its columns can have ? How do you recognize a row that is a fake/test call ? How do you recognize an ineligible call ? We need precise informations, else we can't make a precise answer.

Comment: We have a list of 108 customer IDs which are test calls. These need to be eliminated from the raw data.

Comment: @LanceDacey - You should define a table for the test call ids, and probably one each for the other types of ids - for one thing, that would allow you to add stuff like auditing information.  Simply putting it in the query is asking for trouble... somebody's going to forget an id, use the wrong one, or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE CustomerID IN (
       SELECT CustomerID 
       FROM Table1
       WHERE SiteID IN ('Site1', 'Site2'))
AND CustomerID not in (108 different values)
AND OwnerID <> (A)
AND SenderID <> (A)
AND not ( CreatorID = (A) and
            CallType in ( CallType1, CallType2 ) )
```

Comment: Let me try this. Do I literally paste all 108 values or should I make a separate table for test call IDs and refer to that instead?  I could even make a separate table for the two call types if that would make it easier or faster.

Comment: Adding a separate table for the test ids would make it much more readable. If there's many rows in Table1 and you index correctly a separate table may be faster too. A table for the CallTypes seems overkill but depends on your situation.

Comment: How do you refer to a table in a WHERE statement? Like if the ID is in that table then those rows would NOT be included.

Comment: The easiest option is `customerid not in ( select someId from sometable where a = b )`. You can also use `not exists ( ... )` but that's a little more tricky and not necssary in your case.